# Cordova 3.1.0, AngularJS, WP8 .xap works in emulator not on device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have an app with Cordova 3.1.0 and AngularJS for WindowsPhone8.

It works when i build it with PhoneGap Build ( i've prepared my app for a phonegap build ) and deploy the .xap in an emulator but not when i deploy the same .xap to a WP8 device, i get a black screen.

But the same build for Android works just fine on an Android device.

I've tried and build the .xap with Visual Studio. Once again the .xap works on an emulator but not on a device

What could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: I got the WP8 app with native features working  when i deploy directly to a device with cordova's CLI.

But when i use the .xap that came from that build, i still get the blackscreen.

I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the file `cordova.js` (when you shouldn't be)?

Comment: Yes , i was doing this. But even when i removed it from my index.html and my www folder, the build files only work for Android and iOS. Windows Phone 8 still only works on deploy from project. I'll update this when i get it working. Thnx